# UTF-8 CJK characters not displaying in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, cjk

I've been reading up on Unicode and UTF-8 encoding for a while and I think I understand it, so hopefully this won't be a stupid question:

I have a file which contains some CJK characters, and which has been saved as UTF-8.  I have various Asian language packs installed and the characters are rendered properly by other applications, so I know that much works.

In my Java app, I read the file as follows:

```
// Create objects
fis = new FileInputStream(new File("xyz.sgf"));
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);

// Read and display file contents
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

The output shows the CJK characters as '???'.  A call to `is.getEncoding()` confirms that it is definitely using UTF-8.  What step am I missing to make the characters appear properly?  If it makes a difference, I'm looking at the output using the Eclipse console.

Comment: what is the IDE(Netbeans, Eclipse, etc...) you are using?

Comment: I tried it with the arabic characters before and the I had the same issue. But when I placed a beak point and checked the string I saw the string displayed correctly. I printed it out in a file and it was OK.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Further testing has confirmed it's just my Eclipse config that's the issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
System.out.println(sb);
```

The problem is the above line. This will encode character data using the default system encoding and emit the data to STDOUT. On many systems, this is a lossy process.

If you change the defaults, the encoding used by `System.out` and the encoding used by the console must match.

The only supported mechanism to change the default system encoding is via the operating system. *(Some will advise using the `file.encoding` system property, but this is [not supported](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4163515) and may have unintended side-effects.)* You can use [setOut](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) to your own custom `PrintStream`:

```
PrintStream stdout = new PrintStream(System.out, autoFlush, encoding);
```

You can change the Eclipse console encoding via the [Run configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/launchers/common.htm).

*You can find a number of posts about the subject on my blog - via my profile.*

Comment: Very informative, thankyou.  Unfortunately I can't vote this answer up yet as my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: I've changed the run configuration to use UTF-8, and I impemented a custom PrintStream as follows: 'PrintStream utfout = new PrintStream(System.out, false, "UTF-8");  System.setOut(utfout);', but the characters still don't display properly in the Eclipse console window.  Strangely, they've gone from displaying as '?' to a square block instead, so something's happening.  Just not sure what.

Comment: @Twicetimes - That's actually better, but this is where it can get tricky. On my system, despite using _Courier New_ which doesn't support Chinese graphemes, font substitution is used to render Chinese strings. I believe SWT on Windows uses Uniscribe, so you might need to read up on the Win32 API to see how this happens. You might just not have the right combination of fonts installed. You could [switch fonts](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-fonts.htm) to one where the code points are [supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map).

Comment: Thanks.  Just tried a handful of different fonts for the console output and 'Lucida Sans Unicode' did the trick.  I didn't realise that certain fonts wouldn't include certain ideographs - thought it was all to do with the encoding.  Consider me educated.

Answer (score 5):

The following program prints CJK characters to the console using TextPad. To see the Korean Hangul and Japanese Hiragana I had to tell Java to change the print stream's encoding to EUC_KR and set the properties of TextPad's tool output window:

- font is Arial Unicode MS
- script is Hangul

---

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

class Hangul {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {

        // Change console encoding to Korean

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "EUC_KR");
        System.setOut(out);

        // Print sample to console

        String go_hello  = "가다 こんにちは";
        System.out.println(go_hello);
    }
}
```

---

Tool Output is:

가다 こんにちは

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you need to change the encoding of the Eclipse console as explained in this [how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console/) article

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your platform, it is highly likely that your console (or windows CMD) does not support or use the UTF-8 characterset, and therefor converts all unmappable characters to a question mark.

On Windows for example CMD almost always uses WIN1252 or a similar single byte characterset.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't expect the Windows cmd to display them correctly, but I thought Eclipse would have.  If this is indeed the root of the problem, can anyone else verify that Eclipse doesn't display certain Unicode characters properly in its console?  Where else could I display the output of the program to test if it is working?

Comment: @Twicetimes: Pipe the output to a file and open that file with a UTF-8 capable editor.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström - Thanks for the suggestion.  I wrote the string straight back out to a file using an OutputStreamWriter with the UTF-8 charset specified, and the resulting file does show the characters correctly in another app, so I guess all's well.  Must just be the Eclipse console that threw me.