# Not able to display special characters

Tags: java

I am unable to display special characters (polish characters) on screen. I have a requirement where I get the data from database which has some special characters.  I get the data in an xml format (The xml is not recognizing it as a string) and pass it to action where I try to display the data.  I am trying to get the Uniciode of the special character as `&#X142;` but when I try to display, this gets converted to `&amp;#X142;` and so I am unable to display it because it does not take it as a string.

```
String ex1="ł";
System.out.println("ex1...."+ex1);
output:: ?
```

I am trying to get the Unicode using the following code::

```
    public static String convert (String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        String tc = str;
        String output = "";
        char[] ca = tc.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ca.length; ++i) 
             {
               char a = ca[i];
               if ((int) a > 255) 
                    {
            output += "&"+"#X"+ Integer.toHexString((int) a) + ";";
               } 
                   else 
                   {
            output += a;
              }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

The output is: If input is given as `str="ł"` then `output=&#X142;`

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel! Use the [escapeXml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) method of the [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) class from the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) library, which makes for this simple solution:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(input);
```

Comment: when we try to send StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("&#322;"), we are getting the output as amp;&#322. But i want "ł" to be printed as output.

Comment: Call `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("ł")` to get "&#322;", which is the correct XML encoding of your character. To render the character back to `ł`, display the encoded XML in whatever client is reading it, eg a browser

Answer (score 2):

Set the content type of the page as UTF-8.

Also make sure to set the response header as well to UTF-8. Refer - http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *positively* sure on what you're asking (whether you want to store the character as xml, print it to console, etc) but to do unicode you prefix the unicode code point with \uXXXX, so for example

```
String str = "\u00F6";
char c = '\u00F6';
```

would be for the character ö.

Note that this was taken off [enter link description here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/convertintro.html)

Comment: That's the Java notation, not xml

Answer (score 0):

When you want to write polish characters in console windows you use (redirect System.out!!!)

Look at:
[UTF-8 CJK characters not displaying in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965195/utf-8-cjk-characters-not-displaying-in-java)

I tested:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "Cp852"));

System.out.println("ex1...."+ex1);
```

...and it work's!!!! - display polish letters in cmd window.

Powodzenia!!!