# Read unicode text file with streams?

Tags: java

So I am trying to read textual data from the file and I am messing with Unicode characters, but it seems to not be able to parse Unicode characters properly. I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong as I recently started learning more on Java so I'd appreciate if anyone could point out possible bugs or what is that causes this behavior.

Code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\hello.txt"), "UTF8"));
            char[] buffer = new char[128];
            int len = br.read(buffer);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                System.out.print(buffer[i]);
            }
```

The characters inside of the file are: **Øßà**

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually UTF8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you missing the dash?: UTF-8

If you were using google's Guava libraries then there are constants for [Charsets](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html).

Then you could use:

```
String text =  com.google.common.io.Files.toString(new File("C:\\hello.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);
```

**EDIT**

It is probably due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965794/1089998)?

Comment: It's the same, and it outputs the same results either way.